Why isn't the vowel in the words "warm" and "war" (in American English) pronounced like the one in the word "talk" (American English)?
Right. What is the actual reason?

Because of the "r" (and "l") (and possibly the "w" has some effect too).

Why would you expect them to be pronounced the same way? Think of all the ways "ough" gets pronounced.

This question was closed as a duplicate of the wrong question. For a better answer, see the Wikipedia article on r-colored vowels.

@PeterShor I've reopened it so you guys can pick the duplicates you think better apply. I've also linked to many related questions in the sidebar. The OED explains that this is because of the w- more than the -r, but this varies by speaker. So war, warrior, warn, warm, warship, dwarf, wharf, wart have [ɔ] or for those with tense–lax neutralization before /r/, also [o], while many speakers have [ɔ] in want, water and some have [ɔ~o] in Lawrence, lawyer. Plus some speakers split homophones warn, worn etc.

@tchrist: I think the question is asking why the vowels of talk and war, which are the same in British English, are different in American English, not why the vowels of ward and bard are different. Let me see if I can find a duplicate.

@PeterShor Oh then if that is the actual question being asked then it's the pre-R leveling to only tense vowels for "most" Americans (just like in Mary, merry, marry or very, vary), hence /wɔk/, /tɔk/ in walk, talk but /woɹ/, /toɹ/ in wore¦war, tore for most of us. I don't know where that one gets best answered here.

@tchrist: I couldn't find a good duplicate, so I wrote an answer.

"the vowels of talk and war, which are the same in British English, are different in American English" - only if you pronounce water incorrectly too. "ward and bard are different" - waaar and waaater are the same. It's not wouter.

I would put the question differently: what makes war different from bar, car, far, jar, mar, tar (and words containing these syllables)?  Are there no English words with /war/, and if not why not?

@Mazura There's no such thing as an "incorrect" pronunciation from a native speaker. In any event, your "spelling pronunciations" are the opposite of helpful:  they're actually harmful. Please use IPA or don't bother. The vowel in American warn is the same /o/ you find in woe (minus the trailing offglide), not the same /ɔ/ as in talk, which in the UK is phonemic /ɔː/ so phonetic [ɔː] but in the US is /ɔ/ but actually phonetic [ɒ].  The word water has that same vowel on either shore: the one from walk. But war is like woe, wore unlike far on this shore but not on that shore.

@AntonSherwood It's what I said it my answer, where I reference the OED. The leading w- influenced the vowel historically. Notice who, war, worse but wheat, weary, horse.  Even wharves and warbled have /o/ not  /ɔ/  let alone /ɑ/. Good luck finding any exception to this.

@tchrist: quark is an exception — it doesn't have the same vowel as quarry, quart, or quarrel. And that's because it's a new word, so it wasn't around when the sound changed in warn and quart.

@PeterShor I have heard quark both ways; though the war variant not recently.

Pronunciation
It’s because in America, unlike in Britain, the homophone-pair war, wore usually have the tense-o vowel /o/ of woe instead of the lax-o vowel /ɔ/ of talk. So wore and war sound like woe with an R tacked on the end here.
The same thing happens with words like lore and the homophone-triple pour, pore, poor: those all have the same tense /o/ vowel as low and Poe instead of the lax /ɔ/ vowel of law and paw. So lore is low plus an R not law plus an R, and pour, pore, poor is Poe plus an R not paw plus an R.
Warning: US /ɔ/ ≠ UK /ɔ/
Keep in mind that just like how the American /o/ phoneme is different phonetically from the British /o/ phoneme, the America /ɔ/ phoneme is also not the same phonetically as the British phoneme /ɔ/.
Our /ɔ/ is (usually) lower in the mouth than theirs is, so closer to phonetic [ɒ] than to phonetic [ɔ].
Spelling
But if you’re asking merely about spelling, not pronunciation, that’s completely different.
As I earlier mentioned in comments, the OED explains that this is because of the w‑ more than the ‑r, but this varies by speaker.
So war, warden, warren, warranty, warrior, ward, reward, warble, warn, warm, swarm, warship, dwarf, wharf, wart, thwart have tense /o/ for the majority of us who have neutralized the tense–lax contrast before /r/ and so simply always use the tense one (also called the "close" one, or sometimes the "long" one). In the UK, and in a very few remaining places in the US, the lax one is also possible there, but not for most of us.
In contrast, many speakers have lax /ɔ/ in want, water. A few have lax /ɔ/ in Lawrence, lawyer but most have tense /o/ in those two words. Plus some speakers even split homophone-pair warn, worn.

I wouldn't quite say that "wore and war sound like woe with an R tacked on the end here." The glide at the end of woe doesn't exist in war; your claim is only true if you pronounce the vowel in woe as a monophthong.

It's also worth noting that most accents of British English also have the horse-hoarse merger; i.e. they also don't contrast /ɔ/ and /oʊ/ before /ɹ/; Geoff Lindsey's CUBE transcribes both horse and hoarse as /h óː s/.

@alphabet The terminal offglide in the phonetic diphthong is routinely deleted before many consonant codas but not all. So woe /wow/ +R becomes wore /wor/ just like May Day /mej dej/ +T becomes Mate Date /met det/. This glide deletion does not happen before L or nasals, but sometimes causes breaking: Main Dane is /mejn dejn/ and Male Dale is /mejl dejl/, with a schwa inserted after the glide in dialects that do that. Most of us have /ske.rij/ not /skej.rij/ for scary, /sto.rij/ not /stow.rij/ for story, /ti.rij/ not /tij.rij/ for teary, /bu.tij/ not /buw.tij/ for booty.

This answer strikes me as amounting mostly to “it is because it is.”

Wore has the same vowel as the diphthong in woe???

Oxford (Learner's) gives the Gen Am pronunciation of war as /wɔr/

@Araucaria-Him Yes, and that is incorrect. UK phoneticians consistently misrepresent us. Most Americans have only tense vowels before R, never lax ones. The /ɔ/  vowel of wall  /wɔl/ ᴅᴏᴇs ɴᴏᴛ ᴏᴄᴄᴜʀ in war  /woɹ/! Rather the tense /o/ of woe /wow/ does so, except without the final glide. Another such example is law with /lɔ/ but lore /loɹ/ sounding much more like a compressed version of lower /ˈlowəɹ/, /ˈlowɚ/. Similarly the boy diphthong is tenser /oj/ for us, not laxer /ɔj/. Most of us outside Tennessee also have /o/ in lawyer /ˈlojɚ/, making it very unlike law for us.

@Araucaria-Him Similarly our tense–lax neutralization before R means these all have tense /oɹ/ ɴᴇᴠᴇʀ lax /ɔɹ/: boar bore chore core four fore gore hore more oar ore pore pour roar score shore soar spore store tore wore whore yore your – not to mention north force horse hoarse, which again have only /oɹ/. So more is a compressed mower, etc. I cannot explain why this widespread pronunciation is so poorly represented by dictionaries published in the UK (by non-rhotics?), but Kenyon and Knott got it right.

Are you using /o/ for the [eʊ] diphthong there? (What's the actual IPA value as it were?)

@Araucaria-Him No, I'm using /o/ for a monophthong here. The phonetic diphthong  you're thinking of is /ow/. It is not a phonemic diphthong and its offglide is variable, consistently appearing only when it's word-final. There are no minimal pairs contrasting /o/ with /ow/ in English; tense vowels /e i o u/ at the end of the word always have little phonetic off-glides, something not always shown in the orthography. NB: “Also, /oʊ/, along with /eɪ/, can traditionally manifest as monophthongs: [e] and [o], respectively.” (ref).

In American English, 'r' can change the vowel before it. For many speakers, beard does not have quite the same vowel as either bid or bead, father does not have quite the same vowel as farther, and cord does not have quite the same vowel as cawed.
Depending on the speaker's dialect, the vowel of cord and war can be either /o/, /ɔ/, or somewhere in between. Further, it can have r-coloration, which means that the vowel is modified so that it sounds like the vowel and the consonant /r/ are being pronounced simultaneously; see this Wikipedia article on r-colored vowels.
Thus, while some Americans have exactly the same vowel in war and talk, most don't.

It doesn't "sound like" they're being pronounced simultaneously, they are being!

There definitely are a few American accents in which the A in words like "warm" are pronounced similarly (or even the same) as the A in a word like "talk", or " car". These are some of the non-rhotic American varieties, and the St Louis accent. As for the other American accents, which do pronounce certain 'ar' words with an 'or' sound, the r-coloration probably doesn't have much to do with it as the A retains a similar pronunciation as in the word "talk" for "harm" and a few others. What must be at play here, probably is the fact that in English, the same vowel or vowel combination can have multiple different sounds even when followed by the same consonant sound.

Wait a minute — warm doesn't rhyme with harm.
